# Jquery removeAttr from radio group

Tags: jquery, css

I have a group of radio buttons on a form and I want to remove the required and data-msg attribute if any one of them are clicked. Believe this is a selector issue but my code is below.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <p><input type="radio" class="radio1" name="checkbox1" value="1000-2000" required data-msg="Please Check one Box">1,000-2,000</p>
   <p><input type="radio" class="radio1" name="checkbox1" value="2000-3000" required data-msg="Please Check one Box"> 2,000-3,000</p>
   <p><input type="radio" class="radio1" name="checkbox1" value="3000-4000" required data-msg="Please Check one Box">3,000-4,000</p>
 </div>

 $('.form-group input').click(function()
      {
          $(this).removeAttr('required data-msg'); 
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you are using at least v1.7 of jQuery or else you can't do space-separated attributes to remove. You'd have to do `.removeAttr('required').removeAttr('data-msg');`

Comment: the removeAtrr gets rid of both of the attributes.  The issue is that I have to click each radio button to get rid of them.  I want it to remove the attributes from the three inputs after any one of them have been clicked

Comment: Ah I see, what you'll need to do then is replace `$(this)` with `$('.form-group input')` as `$(this)` only affects the clicked element, not the full group if you get me but `$('.form-group input')` will affect all inputs in `.form-group`

Comment: Yes, @user4703663, you can do space-separated values on `.removeAttr()` but only if you are using at least version 1.7 of jQuery, luckily @Blake is using v2.1.1 so he is fine. He just got the selector wrong to target his elements.